# Is there a Google bar for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-toolbar

In Firefox there is an official Google bar (Google Toolbar).

Is there one for Chrome?

**EDIT**

I want the Google bar with the buttons for Gmail, Anlytics etc ... I don't mean the search part of search field ( that you can do from within the url bar , I now ).

Comment: You mean Google Toolbar? If yes, than no, Google Toolbar is only available for IE and Firefox.

Comment: @Kush: Strange - really like those options ... and really like Chrome too.

Comment: Google Chrome is the **browser version** of Google Toolbar...just sayin'

Comment: @studiohack Chrome does not have the button features of the Toolbar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Regarding OP's Edit

As it appears you want features from the Google Toolbar itself, you should know that the majority of these are built in to Chrome. You specifically mention in your post wanting buttons for Gmail, Analytics, etc. There are a few options.

#### Gmail notifications

- The [Google Mail Checker](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff) extension from Google adds a button to your toolbar which shows how many unread messages you have. Clicking the button opens your inbox.
- The [Gmail Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff) extension by a third party is the exact same, but with added code to show desktop notifications when new mail is received.

#### Other Links

You can turn on Chrome's bookmarks bar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Put bookmarks to Analytics and whatever other services you need in that bar.

#### Google Voice

- The [Google Voice addon](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/kcnhkahnjcbndmmehfkdnkjomaanaooo) by Google installs a toolbar button to show unread Google Voice messages, and to send and receive texts and place calls from any page.

---

### Original Answer

In Firefox, there is a dedicated Google search bar:

[image: firefox search bar]

In Chrome, this functionality is built into the URL bar. Just type into the URL bar and hit enter, and it will search:

[image: chrome search]

You can also search from the address bar for any site which supports the [Open Search protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_search). If you have visited the site before, just start typing the URL, for example, "**su**peruser.com", and the address bar will auto-complete the rest of the URL and prompt you to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to search the site. Many sites support this feature.

[image: chrome open search]

[image: chrome open search]

Answer (score 1):

Whilst there is no Google Toolbar for Chrome, this (archived) support page from Google outlines how to get similar features in Chrome:

http://web.archive.org/web/20121107055136/http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=160743